# Is it possible to fire and handle the component events with component itself?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to fire and handle this event with only one component creation. I don't want to use the parent component to handle the event.

Comment: Please share your sample componnet

Comment: screenshots added above. I am not sure whether the codes are valid logically.

Comment: If you want to handle in the same component, then why do you even need a event? Do you have a specific business requirement for this?

Comment: A component event can either be handled by the component itself or it can be handled by any other component which is present in the hierarchy that receives the event. What is meant by the component itself here by definition?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this. I sometimes do this to get back into the render lifecycle.
As you have it setup, you will cause an infinite loop of events... so don't do it like that.

Try something like this:

Component:

```
<aura:registerEvent name="registerEvent" type="c:CompEvent" />
<aura:handler name="registerEvent" event="c:CompEvent" action="{!c.handleRegisterEvent}" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
```

Code:

```
init: function (component,event,helper) {
  component.getEvent('registerEvent').fire();
},

handleRegisterEvent: function (component,event,helper) {
  //do something
},
```

This is the basic skeleton of how you do it, If I understand you correctly.

Comment: I want to see some useful display in the UI ( in my case testApp.app where my component is wrapped) using the events. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Caspar harmer -- Why there is a need of two handlers as you have shown above?

Comment: Although, if you just want to get back "in the life cycle", $A.getCallback is almost always a better choice.

Comment: If you want output to show up in testApp.app, then you need to put a handler there. As long as it's the direct parent of this component it will detect the event. There are two handlers because one is automatically called as part of the rendering sequence by the framework. I do wonder if we have an X/Y problem here...